How to separate multiple selection values of a lookup column into different share point list row so each value should have its own row
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Lookup-Column</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Fruit</td>
<td>Apple
Banana
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Hi, so I have a list which has a multi select lookup column and I want to use power automate to separate those multi select values into each individual rows in a new share point list. (New to power automate need help with detailed steps)
E.g
List A -
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Lookup-Column</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Fruit</td>
<td>Apple
Banana
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

List B -
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Lookup-Column</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Fruit</td>
<td>Apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Fruit</td>
<td>Banana</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

ID.  Name    Lookup column
1    Fruit   Apple
2    Fruit   Banana


You could use following code to separate lookup column
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ms-vb:contains(';')").each(function(){
    var htmlstr = $(this).html();
    var htmlmod = htmlstr.replace(/; <A/g,"</br><A");
    $(this).html(htmlmod);
  });
});

Here is reference
Replace semicolon delimiter in a Lookup column on the list view
